# soi-même et lui-même

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms-réfléchis

Je suis un peu confus concernant l'utilisation de « soi-même » / « lui-même »

Selon Wiktionary leur utilisation serait interchangeable dans certains cas:

[soi-même](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/soi-m%C3%AAme) :
Pour expliquer le deuxième sens, on donne l'exemple suivant: « Faire ses affaires soi-même ». Je suis quasi certain que l'on peut dire « Faire ses affaires lui-même/elle-même »

Si on regarde l'article de [msn](http://www.msn.com/fr-fr/actualite/france/six-mois-ferme-pour-un-gendarme-qui-avait-agress%C3%A9-une-jeune-femme-%C3%A0-son-domicile/ar-AAmMuSc?li=BBoJIji), on trouve que « soi-même » est employé, mais une autre fois et dans la même phrase quasiment c'est « eux-mêmes » (de la famille de lui-même) qui est utilisé.

Quand est-ce que « soi-même » ne doit pas être employé à la place de « lui-même » / « elle-même » et inversement ?

Comment: Je n'aurais peut-être pas dû modifier. *Par rapport à* est souvent empoyé sans bonne raison. Son utilisation normale sert à faire un lien (souvent une comparaison).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez c'était juste pour comprendre. Sinon ça ne me dérange pas du tout. Merci en tout cas pour les explications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Soi* renvoie à une personne indéterminée, générique, alors que *lui* renvoie à une personne déterminée, précise, et au masculin.

« Faire ses affaires » ne précise pas la personne et doit donc être suivi de « soi-même ».

La phrase de MSN

> Le gendarme, qui voulait "faire justice soi-même" …

est douteuse mais acceptable grace à la présence des guillemets qui renvoient à une formule générique. Sans les guillemets, la forme correcte est:

> Le gendarme, qui voulait se faire justice lui-même…

Answer (score 1):

"Soi-même" est indéterminé. Une traduction assez proche en anglais est "*oneself*".

Par exemple, quand on met des verbes à l'infinitif:

> Se faire à manger (pour) soi-même = *To cook for oneself*
>
> Se blesser soi-même = *To injure/hurt oneself*

Les infinitif sont le cas typique, mais il est plus utilisé que *oneself* en anglais. Par exemple :

> meuble à monter soi-même = *self-assembly furniture*

---

En anglais, on va souvent ajouter un sujet plutôt que d'utiliser "*oneself*":

> Pour y arriver, il faut être en paix avec soi-même =(lit.) *To do that, one has to be at peace with oneself*

Mais un anglophone dirait plutôt :

> *To do that, you have to be at peace with yourself*

Ça ne veut pas dire que "soi-même" se traduit par "yourself" pour autant, juste quand dans ce genre de phrase, on préfèrera utiliser un sujet en anglais quand et rester indéterminé en français.

Comment: Ce meuble est à monter soi-même, You have to assemble this piece of furniture yourself.

Comment: Impossibilité de se prendre en charge soi-même/Impossibility of taking care of oneself

Answer (score 1):

On utilise soi-même avec un verbe à l'infinitif et lorsque le sujet est 'on' et donc indéfini.

Comment: « On voulait faire justice nous-mêmes »

Comment: @jlliagre "nous-mêmes" renvoie en réalité à nous et non pas à une personne indéterminée comme le sous-entend le "On". Est-ce que je me trompe?

Comment: Oui, *nous* est sous entendu, Annie a raison, *soi* correspond bien à *on*. Mon commentaire est l'exception qui confirme la règle.